# submit form and load resulting page on drop with dropzone.js

Tags: dropzone.js

I am trying to simply automatically submit my form and load a resulting page when I drop in a single file. I have spent a few hours reading documentation and discussions, but to no avail.

I have seen samples for using a separate submit-button. But I don't want that. In stead it should happen automatically when the file is dropped in.

Hints? Sample code?